# A long accumulated list of warnings from a React's project. Keep them or clear them up?

Tags: reactjs, command-line-interface, warnings

I have a large project at hand in which accumulated a meaningful number of React's warnings of all sorts - mostly useEffect related ones.

The app is running without critical errors, though.

But it is annoying to see all these warnings in every launching/reloading.

I know there's a simple solution of inserting `// eslint-disable-next-line` or even to disable a whole file, but doing this manually for a +300 warnings and many files is hard and time consuming.

[image]

Furthermore I had a bad experience trying to fix all these warnings manually just to have to revert back to the prior commit because it worsened performance of the app somehow and I could not find the root of the issues - which was multiples - among many modified files, even comparing the diffs in the Github did not shed a light on them.

So, do you have a better approach to clear them up or better keep them and follow the "if-it-is-working-do-not-fix-it" principle?

**Note:** this project runs the latest React version 17 with create-react-app, and it is not injected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave them if you want but, at the end, you will have more trouble than benefits in a long-term period. Also it is important, if you decide to act and fix them, to work on a dedicated branch.

Well, I had similar issues in legacy projects and projects that were not configured with a linter from the beginning.

A strategy that i followed can be described in this way:

1. before to start fixing linter-related problems, be sure that the rules defined are as near as possible to the rules you want to check in your codebase

This is an important phase since, if you are planning to fix hundreds of linter-related issues, you don't want to find yourself doing the same job again.

2. check with your team if there are additional rules that need to be added, try to follow a standard across all project

It is important to be aligned with your teammates to prevent that, if a teammate opens a file whit a linter enabled in the code editor that is not configured in the same way of your, your work will be lost. Note that it is a best-practice to include the linter configuration file in the repository of your code. It is to avoid, instead, to put in the repository the configuration files of your editor since they may differ from an environment to another.

3. configure all the commend needed to perform a lint check and a lint fix using the commend-line

For example, in a `package.json` file, you can add something like this, in the scripts section:

```
"lint:check": "eslint ./src/**/*.ts*",
"lint:fix": "eslint ./src/**/*.ts* --fix"
```

4. let start to do the dirty job, call the command you defined before to fix all the automatically-fixable problem

So something like that:

```
yarn link:fix
```

5. Do the manual stuff in order

Start from a type of bug and proceed in order. It is important to proceed by type because, in this way, you can use the search tool of your code editor to search for a given pattern and act, in some cases, with a "copy-and-paste" fix. You may be tempted to proceed one-file-at-time but, in this case, you have to chenge your mindset at every line of code and it is easier to have bugs.

Comment: Nice to hear you've been through this issue, too. The project is equipped with some QA just recently. I implemented some quality testers like ESlint for errors checking, prettier for code formatting and husky for applying and checking these automatically before committing the code to Git from now.  I will take you type-of-bug advice and categorize by area in the project and do it progressively while developing so I can detect more easily some leaking memory which was the biggest issue I faced and forced me to reverse the code back.